# CURL SSL Connect Error during install of Sitelock on Centos 6 server

Tags: ssl, centos6, plesk, sitelock

I am trying to install Sitelock with Plesk 11 on my GoDaddy Centos 6.4 VPS. When I access Sitelock 1.0 through the Applications tab and click the install button I get this error:

> Error: Installation of Sitelock failed. Non-zero exit status returned
>   by script. Output stream: 'CURL error. API request failed with
>   message:SSL connect error '.

Google does not return a result for this exact error message and none that I can find sound specifically related. I am not familiar with cURL. Digicert indicates the SSL is correctly installed and COMODO SSL Analyzer doesn't indicate any problems. How can I resolve this?

Comment: I believe cURL uses NSS on Fedora, Red Hat and CentOS.

Comment: Thanks but what does that mean for me in practical terms?

Comment: I think it means its not related to OpenSSL. Invoke `curl` with `--trace` to get details on the failure. Also, what does this have to do with programming or development?

Comment: Sorry -- I guess I should have been in serverfault. My bad.

Comment: If a moderator reads this -- please move to Serverfault.